# How to get the declared size of a varchar2 in oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, size, sqldatatypes

Trying to get the size of a defined variable in Oracle.  I may need to use a number when declaring the size of a varchar2 but would rather not have to keep track of an extra variable or number.

example pseudo code:

```
declare 
  myvar varchar(42) := 'a';
begin

  /* I know the length is length(myvar) = 1. */
  /* but how do I get 42? */
  /* What is the max defined size of this variable */
  declared_size_of(myvar);  
end
```

The reason I need this is to lpad the length of the string to the declared size so it doesn't generate an exception.

Comment: I don't think you can.  Just declare a constant and move on.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, is there any way we can then use the constant to declare the size of the variable?

Comment: It may help to have a little more context here.  Will this code really run in an anonymous block, or will it be part of an object?  If it's an object, then PL/Scope may be able to tell you the variable size, if you know exactly where the variable comes from.  But then if you know where the variable is coming from, why not just hard-code the number?  If you don't know where the variable comes from, you'll probably be stuck writing a loop that increments until there is an exception, and handle the exception.

Comment: Why would a non-padded string generate an exception?  That seems like a bug that should be fixed elsewhere.  If a padded string is a requirement, given that the semantics of a `char(x)` variable is to always be padded out to the appropriate length, why wouldn't you use `char` instead of `varchar2` if you really need a padded string?

Comment: Do you actually get an exception?  Or do you just think you might?  Please post actual exception message.

Comment: I haven't been able to get the constant number or integer to work.  CONST_NUMBER INTEGER := 80;  myvar varchar(CONST_NUMBER INTEGER) := 'a';  -- Doesn't work right.

Answer (score 1):

As @Justin said in his comments, you don't have to explicitly blank pad the string if you use **CHAR** data type. Oracle would blank-pad the value to it's maximum size.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS346),

> If the data type of the receiver is CHAR, PL/SQL blank-pads the value
>   to the maximum size. Information about trailing blanks in the original
>   value is lost.

For example,

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    myvar CHAR(42);
  3  BEGIN
  4    myvar:='a';
  5    dbms_output.put_line(LENGTH(myvar));
  6  END;
  7  /
42

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Brute Force technique using exception handling which is probably very inefficient:

```
 DECLARE
   myvar varchar2(42) := 'a'; /* using varchar */
   v_size number := null;
   x varchar(4000) := '';
   v_length number := 0;
   BEGIN
     begin
        v_length := length(myvar);
        x := myvar;
        FOR i in v_length..8001 LOOP
           myvar := myvar || ' '; /* add one space at a time until it causes an exception */
        End Loop;   
        EXCEPTION
           -- WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
              WHEN OTHERS THEN
                v_length := length(myvar);
     end;
     dbms_output.put_line('Declared size is varchar('||v_length
                          ||') and length(myvar) is '||length(trim(myvar)));
   END;
```

Comment: Yes, it is very inefficient because you are first looping through and then the logic is in the exception block. By the way, using brute force would be even more inefficient if the size declared is even more. `VARCHAR2` can take a maximum of `32767` in `PL/SQL`. Thus, for your requirement the best way to do is as I have shown in my answer, use `CHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the max. of a column input, you simply could do:

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(Column)) 
FROM TableA;
```

Comment: Wondering if that will work on a varchar2 declared variable.  I'll give it a try in the morning.

Comment: It doesnt work because it returns the size of the actual data stored into that column, not the maximum size of the data you could store there. It reads the whole table (all records) to calculate that value.